# Angularjs - Argument 'homeController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-controller

I have an ionic application that gives me below mentioned error when navigating `homeController's scope.

Here's my app.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  //external modules
  'ionic',
  //feature modules
  'home',
  'events',
  'news'
])
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('main', {
      url: '/',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/main-nav.html'
    })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

    .state('main.home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        'main-home': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/main-home.html',
          controller: 'homeController'
        }
      }
    });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
)}
```

Here's my controller:

```
app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', '$stateParams',
  function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.homeTitle = 'News';
  }
]);
```

Here's my index.html:

```
<body ng-app="app">

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

Here's my template:

```
<ion-view view-title="News">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    Hello world!
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I have gone through similar questions available in here, but couldn't find one that appeals with this. can someone point me out where did I go wrong?

Comment: one possibility is, could you double check that `homeController` js has been added to page?

Comment: could you create a http://plnkr.co/ so we can check it in action?

Answer (score 0):

I would build controller like this one:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('homeController', homeController);

function homeController () {

}
```

In your app.js must be a semicolon after this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  //external modules
  'ionic',
  //feature modules
  'home',
  'events',
  'news'
])
```

--

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  //external modules
  'ionic',
  //feature modules
  'home',
  'events',
  'news'
]);
```

Additionaly I would put each controller into anonymous function:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    // js

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo that was bothering me. My bad!

Changed

```
<script srv="js/scripts/home/controllers/home-controller.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/scripts/home/controllers/home-controller.js"></script>
```